# Matrix column access without numpy

Tags: python, loops, matrix

I am trying to write a program to for multiplying matrices without the use of numpy.

```
columns = [[], [], []]

for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
    columns[0].append(matrix[i][0])
    columns[1].append(matrix[i][1])
    columns[2].append(matrix[i][2])
```

The code I have can obtain the columns of a matrix but only for a 3x3 matix, and if I wanted to use say a 2x2 matrix the code would not work unless I specify for that case. Is there a way to access the ith column of a matrix in a loop so that the columns of the matrix can be accessed without first knowing the size?

Comment: You are accessing `matrix` with a variable from a loop so you know how to do that. Why don't you apply the same for `columns`?

Comment: Yes, just loop directly over the columns. You probably shouldn't 't be using `for i in range(...)` ever, maybe sometimes `for i, column in enumerate(columns): ...`

Comment: Are you just trying to copy `matrix`? Because for that, `[column.copy() for column in matrix]` would work

Answer (score 0):

Get the other size from `matrix` as well:

```
for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
    for j in range(0, len(matrix[i])):
        columns[j].append(matrix[i][j])
```

You could initialize `columns` like so:

```
columns = [[] for x in matrix[0]]
```

(this assumes every row has the same number of columns as the first).

Comment: What about arbitrary matrix sizes, like a 4x9?

Comment: What about them?

Comment: Sorry, I mean ones with more dimensions like 4x3x5 - your code doesn't handle them.

Comment: Question wasn't about arbitrary number of dimensions.

Comment: Could just be the way I'm reading it, but I think that what is implied. The example code in the question is for a 3x3x3 and then they mention about another that's **say** 2x2.